# asp.net membership tables not available for gridview databinding?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, membership

I want to bind gridview to aspnet_Membership table so the admin can update username and passwords if he needs to. 
But for some reason I can't access all the asp.net membership tables when I am configuring sqldatasource for the gridview.
Any idea why is that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by this point you have verified you have the `aspnet_Membership` table in your database.  Also, what is the security context of the login that you are using in your connection string to access the database?  Does that mapped user have the necessary permissions to view this table?

The best way to find that out is to login to SSMS as the login in your connection string for your application and try to access that table.  That'll narrow down the problem for you.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes I have that table in the database, including all the other asp.net membership tables. It's weird because none of the asp.net membersip tables are available for selection, but I can select from the other tables which are not related to the asp.net membership provider. Also I am able to login with SSMS. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Laziale if you can, run a SQL Trace to see what is exactly happening from your client application calls to the database.  Then you can step through that and recreate and see where the problem is.